# Mutually exclusive knockout observablearrays

Tags: knockout.js

I have a dropdown which is a master list of customer objects (available customers populated from server) with a Add button next to it which will add the customer to the table at the bottom with Remove button next to each row.

My HTML code:

```
                <div class="mbody">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select style="width: 20em;" data-bind="options: customerList, optionsText: 'Name', value: selectedCustomer">
                        </select>
                        &nbsp;<button type="button" data-bind="click: addCustomerToSelected">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <table class="table">
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: customers">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <strong data-bind="text: Name"></strong>

                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" data-bind="click: $parent.removeCustomerFromSelected">Remove</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

My Knockout code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function CustViewModel(serverData) {
      var self = this;
      self.customerList = ko.observableArray();
      //display existing selected customers
      self.customers = ko.observableArray(serverData.SelectedCustomers);
      self.selectedCustomer = ko.observable();

      self.addCustomerToSelected = function () {
        self.customers.push(selectedCustomer());
        self.customerList.remove(self.selectedCustomer());
      }
      self.removeCustomerFromSelected = function (customerRow) {
        self.customers.remove(customerRow);
        self.customerList.push(customerRow);
      }
   }
</script>
```

How do I make the dropdown subscribe to the change event of selectedCustomers observable array such that when item is deleted or added to the selectedCustomers, the customerList automatically deletes or adds those items in its list.

So if I choose "Jeff" from the customerList dropdown & click Add, it should be added to the selectedCustomers table underneath & then deleted from the customerList dropdown. And when I delete it from the selectedCustomers table, then it should be added back to the customerList dropdown.

Currently, I have the code handle that in the add & remove functions, but the issue I am facing is that the dropdown of customerList when initially loaded from Server, does not exclude the customers that are there in the selectedCustomer list below.

Answer (score 1):

A really good model for this is to use a computed arrays. Say you have one array `customers` - you can have two computeds, `availableCustomers` and `selectedCustomers`:

```
self.customers = ko.observableArray();
self.availableCustomers = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.customers().filter(function (customer) { 
        return !customer.selected()
    });
});
self.selectedCustomers = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.customers().filter(function (customer) { 
        return customer.selected()
    });
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6Q373/1/). Note that one thing I did was make up some server data and map it to a child view model to which I added a property "selected" which is what determines the selected state of each item.

This way, each item has a state, and you don't have to worry about deciding when to add or remove it from which list, it's either selected, or it isn't.

#### Update:

To handle where you're getting a list of customers, then a separate list of selected customers, just get the master list first, get the selected list, and mark all matching customers in the master list as selected.

Here's an [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Q373/2/) example, and the relevant code:

```
// In your master list ajax result:
 self.customers(serverData.map(function(customer) {
    return new CustomerViewModel(customer);
 }));

// in your selected list ajax result:
  // for each selected item, mark it's corresponding ViewModel in the master list as selected
 for(var i = 0; i < selectedCustomers.length; i++) {
    // use the Id property (or some other unique key to match a selected item up to the master - you can't just compare objects
    var matchingCustomer = findById(self.customers(), selectedCustomers[i].id);
    matchingCustomer.selected(true);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome example. How will the code work in the scenario where the server is also sending a list of selected customers it currently has. So when the page first loads, it sends a master list of customers & also list of currently selected customers which has to be displayed in the table initially (& won't be there in the master list coming from the server).